# Why am I getting an Invalid Procedure call or argument on a Range union

Tags: excel, vba, runtime-error

As the final step before checking for blank cells, I create a range to use in the check.  That range is based on some fixed sets and how the sets go together is variable.  All the application.unions work fine except for the final one.  I had all my variables defined globally in a module, I tried taking the sub specific variables and defining them just in my sub.  I made sure to remove one set that isn't finished because it might be empty.  I still get an Invalid Procedure error.

The public variables are in Module1.  There is a sub that runs on workbook open that defines the ranges being used.  Here is the sub running before save:

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)

Dim Drive As Range
Dim Stage As Range
Dim Required As Range

'Create the final range of cells for checking
If Module1.DriveChk = "G" Then
    Set Drive = Module1.Engine
ElseIf Module1.DriveChk = "E" Then
    Set Drive = Module1.Motor
End If

If Module1.StageChk = 1 Then
    Set Stage = Module1.Stage1
End If

If Module1.StageChk = 2 Then
    Set Stage = Application.Union(Module1.Stage1, Module1.Stage2)
End If

If Module1.StageChk = 3 Then
    Set Stage = Application.Union(Module1.Stage1, Module1.Stage2, Module1.Stage3)
End If

Set Required = Application.Union(Module1.Fixed, Drive)

'Check if all required cells are filled in
If WorksheetFunction.CountA(Required) < Required.Count Then
    Cancel = True
    MsgBox "Please Completed Shaded Cells!", vbOK + vbExclamation, "SAVE CANCELLED"

End If

'Set the report date before saving
Range("AG60") = Format(Now(), "mm-dd-yyyy hh:mm:ss AM/PM")

'Old code probably to ensure saving macro enabled that is currently commented out
'  Dim sFN As String
 '   If SaveAsUI Then
  '      Cancel = True
   '     sFN = Application.GetSaveAsFilename(, _
    '       fileFilter:="Excel Macro-Enabled Workbooks (*.xlsm),*.xlsm")
     '   Debug.Print sFN
      '  If sFN <> "False" Then _
       '     ThisWorkbook.SaveAs sFN, xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled
    'End If
End Sub
```

The error occurs on Set Required = Application.Union(Module1.Fixed, Drive)

I can post the other code if needed.

Comment: Ranges being unioned are all set and all on the same worksheet?

Comment: There are no named ranges in the worksheet itself.  These are programatically defined ranges in VBA.  An example would be Set Module1.Fixed = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1,C3,F40").

Comment: I wasn't asking about named ranges - I was asking if all the range variables were set to a range before being used in Union, and if they're all on the same worksheet.

Comment: Try adding Debug.Print  `Module1.Fixed.Address(), Module1.Fixed.Parent.Name` and the same for Drive just before the failing `Union` call

Comment: All base ranges are set to a range on workbook open.  This particular range however, is the one that is made up of range variables that are adjusted per user input (selecting check boxes).  The unions based on the checkboxes seem to work but this final union to make the final check set fails.

Comment: Sorry for my ignorance but you must have meant me to alter part of your suggested debug line as it fails for me.

Comment: If you fill your `Module1`-Variables at Workbook-Open and run your code later: Are you sure that all your variables are still filled? There are several things that could cause that they where reset in the meantime: Unhandled errors, code recompile and some more.

Comment: I assume that's what Tim was having me check for, I'm just having trouble formatting the debug commands to work right.

Comment: Ok, I think I formatted them correctly.  The issue is apparently with how I'm handling my dynamic ranges.  They are definitely "nothing" per the debug which will error the union.  I think I'm beginning to understand the issues I'm having are with variables being flushed on error and/or needing initialized differently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was trying to union a range that was "nothing" which always throws an error with Application.Union

Adding the following code:

```
Debug.Print Module1.Fixed.Address, Module1.Fixed.Parent.Name
Debug.Print Drive.Address, Drive.Parent.Name
```

helped me troubleshoot and see what was going on.